# Php longblob to img

Tags: php, database

I have a function that calls on a database class, and asks for a list of images.
This below is the function.

```
//Hämtar en array av filer från disk.
public function GetFiles()
{   

    $sql = "SELECT pic FROM pictures";
    $stmt = $this->database->Prepare($sql);

    $fileList = $this->database->GetAll($stmt);
    echo $fileList;
    if($fileList)
    {
        return $fileList;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this is my database class method that GetFiles calls.

```
public function GetAll($sqlQuery) {

        if ($sqlQuery === FALSE)
        {
            throw new \Exception($this->mysqli->error);
        }
        //execute the statement
        if ($sqlQuery->execute() == FALSE)
        {
            throw new \Exception($this->mysqli->error);
        }
        $ret = 0;
        if ($sqlQuery->bind_result($ret) == FALSE)
        {
            throw new \Exception($this->mysqli->error);
        }

        $data = array();
        while ($sqlQuery->fetch())
        {
            $data[] = $ret;
            echo $ret;
        }

        $sqlQuery->close();

        return $data;
    }
```

The GetFiles function return value is then later processed by another function

```
public function FileList($fileList)
{
    if(count($fileList) == 0)
    {
        return "<p class='error'> There are no files in array</p>";
    }

    $list = '';
    $list .= "<div class='list'>";
    $list .= "<h2>Uploaded images</h2>";
    foreach ($fileList as $file) {

        $list .= "<img src=".$file." />";
    }
    $list .= "</div>";
    return $list;
}
```

But my database just returns the longblob as a lot of carachters, how do i get the longblob to display as images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to base64 encode it and pass it in via a data URI, e.g.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($file) ?>" />
```

However, if you're serving up "large" pictures, this is going to make for a hideously bloated page, with absolutely no way to cache the image data to save users the download traffic later on. You'd be better off with an explicitly image-serving script, e.g.

```
<img src="getimage.php?imageID=XXX" />
```

and then have your db code in that script:

```
$blob = get_image_data($_GET[xxx]);
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo $blob;
```

Problems like this are why it's generally a bad idea to serve images out of a database.

Answer (score 1):

If you're embedding it as part of a webpage, then you should use the [`data` URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Better would be to have the `<img>` tag point to a PHP file that sets the correct `Content-Type` header and dumps the image data.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to save the image to the filesystem and load from there for the following reasons:

- It's expensive on the database, and databases are harder to scale
- It uses many system resources for a minor task
- Internet Explorer, especially IE8, would give error for src over 34k long

Look into a CDN option.

If you insist

```
$list  = sprintf("<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,%s\" />",base64_encode($file));
```

Comment: what do you meen by saving and load the pictures, how would i do this, i am new at php..sorry

Comment: 1. Don't save the images to MySQL , and it it has been saved .. Copy it to a cache folder and only retrieve new images .. if you need help with this let me know ....