# Can't display image on dreamweaver from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I upload some image to phpMyAdmin, and write some code on Dreamweaver.

[image: on phpmyadmin]

Then got this:

[image: on chrome]

The code is on below:

```html
<?php
    require_once("connection.php");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM food");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Food & Beverages</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<table width="400" border="1">
  <tbody>
  <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  ?>
    <tr>
      <td width="240" height="130"><img src="<?php echo $row['image']?>"></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['info'];?></td>
    </tr>
      <?php }?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What type of column is image? Its better to store paths no images in mysql in most cases (certainly for yours).

Comment: longblob, I can't insert it when I choose varchar

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785740/php-longblob-to-img