# PHP:Retrieving images from a database query issues

Tags: php

I have read many posts but i cannot find my answer.
I am developing a food order/delivery website, which has many food cuisine categories, African, Alcohol, American... Each category is meant to have a different header image. So if the admin creates a new restaurant, when they select the restaurant cuisine, the correct header image will automatically display on the main websites products page for that said restaurant.

I have manually inputted the images into the database already, now i am trying to retrieve the database, my or die statement prints that it is not, but i have no error messages, which is confusing me.

```
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);
    if (isset($_GET['rest_id'])) {

        $Rest = $_GET['rest_id'];

        $get_cat_img = "SELECT Cuisine_category
        FROM Rest_Category,Category_img
        INNER JOIN Rest_Details
        ON Rest_Category.Cat_ID = Rest_Details.Cat_ID
        WHERE Rest_Details.Cat_ID='$Rest'";

        $results = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_cat_img) or die("query is not working");
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($results) or die ("q not working");
        $img=$row['Category_img'];
        echo $row['Category_img'];

        echo '<img src="'.$img.'" alt="background" style="width:100%;height:300px">';           
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: What is `Category_img` a table or an column name?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is the column name

Comment: `or die("query is not working")` that doesn't help you here, should your query have failed, `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` will, as will http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Hiya Ralph, I some how knew you would be lurkin, so I already added that to my answer @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly *Ah, well will ya lookah dat!* hehe. Let's see if anything comes of it. Spidey sense huh?

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have error handling at the top of my page,

Comment: @Monroe do a var_dump to see what's going through there or not. What's going on right now? Does anything echo at all, look at your HTML source also. also what is the column type for the image and the data?

Comment: @Fred-ii- column type is longblob

Comment: @Monroe see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12785796/ your present method is failing you because of it. also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13225760/ that's why you get those `?` marks.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you. I shall look into it

Comment: @Monroe you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have just put a column name in the wrong place in your query.

If `Category_img` is a column name in the `Rest_Category` table, this is what you want to do

```
$get_cat_img = "SELECT Cuisine_category,Category_img
                FROM Rest_Category
                  INNER JOIN Rest_Details ON Rest_Category.Cat_ID = Rest_Details.Cat_ID
                WHERE Rest_Details.Cat_ID='$Rest'";
```

You can also shorten things a bit by using Alias's, it often makes the SQL code easier to read when it get past the very simple query.

```
$get_cat_img = "SELECT rc.Cuisine_category,rc.Category_img
                FROM Rest_Category rc
                  INNER JOIN Rest_Details rd ON rc.Cat_ID = rd.Cat_ID
                WHERE rd.Cat_ID='$Rest'";
```

Also modify your error reporting to actually report the real MYSQL error, it is much more usful that any message you can some up with

Like so

```
$results = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_cat_img);
if ( $result === false ) {
    echo 'query is not working: ' . mysqli_error($dbc);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it likes inner join, i just performed to see if a simple query would work select * FROM .... and the query works, weird

Comment: Difficult to help here as I dont know your database schema

Comment: Also make sure you have linked these tables correctly  `Rest_Category.Cat_ID = Rest_Details.Cat_ID` without that it is not going to work as you expect

Comment: @RiggsFolly http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php also ;-) just in case.

Comment: I was just looking that statement up. One of many holes in my knowlwdge!

Comment: @RiggsFolly you think they need a `while` loop here?

Comment: @RiggsFollyi think you are right about the ON... i just deleted that and it works to some extent, adding back in the error message appears, i will look into that. I should have mentioned i have error reporting right at the top of my page

Comment: Ralph, I think `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);` is just _adding an extra error reporting to say_ You are not using an index in this query @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly *10-4 Smokey*

Comment: Ralph, well he has obviously solved it judging by the acceptance @Fred-ii- With a little help from his friends

Comment: found the issue, i believe. You have been great help! just now have to work out why i am seeing a ?mark instead of a the actual image.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  [*Right here Smokey...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100528/phpretrieving-images-from-a-database-query-issues?noredirect=1#comment61744493_37100528) as per the above comment by the OP. Pretty sure that's the clincher here ;-)

Comment: @Monroe Its far easier to store a path to an image on disk in the database than store the actual image in a blob on the database

Comment: @RiggsFolly oops! i am very new to this. Is that the better way to receive my goal

Comment: That is the way I would personnaly approach it